# Including greek letters when saving matrix from R to .tex table

Tags: tables, r, greek, xtable, statistics

How does one save a table with Greek letters in R, so that LaTeX recognizes and outputs the Greek letters when the table is called in LaTeX ?

I am using R to output a table of results, save the results table as a `*.tex` file using R's `print()` command, and I input this table of results in my longer `*.tex` report.

As you can see below in the below R code, I want to include Greek letters as row labels, but I cannot figure it out.

R code is:

```
table <- rbind(1:5, 6:10, 11:15, 16:20)

rownames(table) <- c("hat(beta)",
                     "hat(tau)",
                     "hat(sigma)_C",
                     "gamma")

colnames(table) <- c("Var1",
                     "Var2",
                     "Var3",
                     "Var4",
                     "Var5")

print(xtable(table), only.contents=TRUE, include.rownames=T, 
      include.colnames=T, floating=F,
      file = 'table.tex')
```

Tex code:

```
  \begin{tabular}{  l cc cc c   }
          \hline
     \input{table.tex} 
          \hline
        \end{tabular}
```

Comment: My first impression is that this is not a latex problem per se, unless there are specific tools for using R along with latex. It seems that all you need is a script that prepends a backlash to all the words that correspond to greek letters (alpha,beta,gamma, ..) Are you using linux by any chance?

Comment: @geo909 I'm using mac osx, not linux. I considered posting this at stackoverflow, but I opted for tex.stack since this is ultimately about using tex, although there are probably work-arounds in both R and Tex. I'll try that prepend idea now

Comment: @geo909 I found the answer on stackoverflow and posted an answer below

Answer (score 3):

I solved this on the `R` end rather than the tex end. But for future reference the solution is below.

I found the necessary help here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732712/handling-latex-backslashes-in-xtable

The necessary steps in R are using double backslashes and `sanitize.colnames.function = identity` or `sanitize.rownames.function = identity`.

```
colnames(table) <- "$\\beta_0$"
print(xtable(table), sanitize.colnames.function = identity)
```

The corrected code from my example is below:

```
table <- rbind(1:5, 6:10, 11:15, 16:20)

rownames(table) <- c("$\\hat{\\beta}$",
                     "$\\hat{\\tau}$",
                     "$\\hat{\\sigma}_C$",
                     "$\\gamma$")

colnames(table) <- c("Var1",
                     "Var2",
                     "Var3",
                     "Var4",
                     "Var5")

print(xtable(table), only.contents=TRUE, include.rownames=T, 
      include.colnames=T, floating=F, sanitize.rownames.function = identity
      file = 'table.tex')
```